# Keypad Type 11 numbers only?

Tags: arduino-ide

Can someone give me any idea what condition should i use in input 11 numbers only in the switch case? I only want to type and input 11 numbers only but The problem is it can type more than 11 numbers.

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include "Keypad.h"

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,16,2);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

const byte Rows= 4; //number of rows on the keypad i.e. 4
const byte Cols= 3; //number of columns on the keypad i,e, 3

//we will definne the key map as on the key pad:

char keymap[Rows][Cols]=
{
{'1', '2', '3'},
{'4', '5', '6'},
{'7', '8', '9'},
{'*', '0', '#'}
};

//  a char array is defined as it can be seen on the above


//keypad connections to the arduino terminals is given as:

byte rPins[Rows]= {1,2,3,4}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte cPins[Cols]= {5,6,7}; //Columns 0 to 2

// command for library forkeypad
//initializes an instance of the Keypad class
Keypad kpd= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rPins, cPins, Rows, Cols);

char entryStr[8];   
int i=0;
long number1=0;
long number2=0;

void setup()
{
   Wire.begin();  
   lcd.init();                       
   lcd.backlight();
   Serial.begin(9600);
   delay(100);

}
```

Comment: I tried that code but the problem is. Its still input more than 11 numbers

Comment: I did upload a photo in Displaying LCD it can input almost 15 numbers. I want only to input 11 numbers

Comment: Am I missing something? You count the number of digits entered, and stop when you have 11 of them. I suggest doing some C tutorials.

Comment: did you ask this same question on March 27th? .... are you Shin Doe? ... if you are, why are you asking again?

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three simple approaches.

1. You could get a string, and limit it to 11 characters in length. You then convert the string to `num`
2. You could check that 9999999999<`num`<=99999999999
3. You could count the number of valid 'kpd.getKey()' and when it gets to 11 exit the function (returning `num` as it stands)

The OP suggests only 11 digits. Of course, if less that 11 digits are acceptable, the returning value could be padded with `0`.

`lcd.print1 can natively takes a string, and the best approach is to treat`num` as a string instead of as a number. A number (in itself) is only useful if you want to do arithmetic. A lot of times a series of digits are used as an identifier - these are not really numbers but strings with a limited character set.

Some examples (not tested):

**Example 1:** counting the digits entered. Simply added a counter `numcount` - you can see where I use it in the conditional loop, where I increment it, and where I clear it.

```
long GetNumber()
{

  long num = 0;
  long numcount = 0;
  char key = kpd.getKey();
  while(key != '#' && numcount <= 11)
  {
    switch (key)
    {
    case NO_KEY:
      break;
    case '0': 
[... skipped for brevity ...]
    case '9':
      lcd.print(key);
      num = num * 10 ;
      num= num+ (key-'0');
      numcount += 1;
      break;
  case '*':
    num = 0;
    numcount = 0;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Re-type number:");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    break;
  }
  key = kpd.getKey();
}
return num;
}
```

**Example 2:** Simple check on the value of `num`. In this case both the "#" and `num` reaching a certain value will exit the function in a controlled way. A better loop method would be to `loop ... until` - checking the condition at the end of the loop rather than at the beginning.

```
long GetNumber()
{
  long num = 0;
  char key = kpd.getKey();
  while(key != '#' && num <= 99999999999)
  {
    switch (key)
    {
    case NO_KEY:
      break;
    case '0': 
    [... skipped for brevity ...]
    case '9':
      lcd.print(key);
      num = num * 10 ;
      num= num+ (key-'0');
      break;
    case '*':
      num = 0;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Re-type number:");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      break;
    }
    key = kpd.getKey();
      }
  return num;
}
```

**Example 3:** using a string. Same comment about checking conditions at the end of the loop instead of the beginning apply. I haven't worked with strings in C for a few decades, so the routines I used (`strlen`, `strcat`) may need some work or tweaking.

```
string GetNumber()
{
  string num = "";
  char key = kpd.getKey();
  while(key != '#' && strlen(num) <= 11)
  {
    switch (key)
    {
    case NO_KEY:
      break;
    case '0': 
    [... skipped for brevity ...]
    case '9':
      lcd.print(key);
      num = strcat(num,key)num * 10 ;
      break;
    case '*':
      num = "";
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Re-type number:");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      break;
    }
    key = kpd.getKey();
    }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . Can you give me idea how to do it in my code?Im really a newbie. thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried your code and its working now. Thank you very much! :) :D